# icon-arrow-right now showing up in my project from a sample at jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I copied a bootstrap tab control sample project from jsfiddle at

[bootstrap tab control sample with dropdown menus](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/3100/)
    ---

to my local workstation as a .htm project (I am Not using visual studio here -- running win7 IE 11).  I added (downloaded) all the referenced .css/.js files referenced in this sample project.  The sample project is working on my workstation.  I even get the down caret on the 2nd menu (tab) item.  but the submenu in the actual sample displays an icon-arrow-right (for an additional submenu).  This icon-arrow-right is not showing up on my work station.

I tried another sample project from jsfiddle using VS2015 which used glyphicons.  I got that working, so I copied the font folder from the VS project to my html project folder and tried using glyphicon-arrow-right in the htm project and referenced bootstrap.min.css but still no arrow-right. I tried a variety of things based on other posts regarding the same problem -- but no luck.

How can I get that icon-arrow-right to show up on my sample project on win7 IE11?

Here's the html code I'm using

```
html>
<head>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">  
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-2.0.2.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="result-light.css">     
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-glyphicons.css">-->

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav {
        padding: 9px 0;
    }

    .dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
        left: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        margin-top: -1px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .navbar .sub-menu:before {
        border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-top: 7px solid transparent;
        left: -7px;
        top: 10px;
    }

    .navbar .sub-menu:after {
        border-top: 6px solid transparent;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 6px solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
        left: 10px;
        top: 11px;
        left: -6px;
    }

    .glyphicon-nonescaped.glyphicon-arrow-right:before { 
        content: "\e092";
    }

  </style>

  <title></title>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){

});//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="brand">Project name</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <!--<a href="#">2-level Dropdown <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>-->
    <a href="#">2-level Dropdown <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right glyphicon-nonescaped"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form action="" class="navbar-search pull-left">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query span2">
          </form>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="#" href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
    <li>
    <a href="#">2-level Menu <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
 <a href="#">Menu</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#">Menu</a>
</li>
</ul>


<script>
// tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
  height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
  slug: "2Smgv"
}], "*")
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I opened up the debugger I saw that this line of CSS set the URL of that image:

```
.btn-link[disabled]:hover,.btn-link[disabled]:focus{color:#333333;text-decoration:none;}
[class^="icon-"],[class*=" icon-"]{display:inline-block;width:14px;height:14px;*margin-right:.3em;line-height:14px;vertical-align:text-top;background-image:url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");background-position:14px 14px;background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-top:1px;}
```

This is from bootstrap-combined.min.css line 381

I believe you need to update the url to:

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/img/glyphicons-halflings.png or whatever path is relevant to that given symbol. It seems as though only a partial piece of the URL to the image is being presented.

Comment: outstanding!  Nice catch.  Now I have my arrow (my dumb little arrow :) ).  Thank you very much for the help.